# Conditional formatting across sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have two sheets, `SheetA` for values, `SheetB` for calculations. I want a cell in `SheetA` to be colored, if a value in `SheetB` satisfies a condition.

Normally, referencing a field from another sheet is done with `='SheetB'!C1`. However, this yields an "invalid formula" when put into the input box for conditional formatting with a formula.

Is it possible to reference a field in `SheetB` for conditional formatting in `SheetA` without the workaround of first mirroring the relevant values of `SheetB` in `SheetA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was trying to achieve the result across spreadsheets before (rather than sheets). If you put a number in A1 of SheetB and in A1 of SheetA Conditional formatting... like so:

[image: WA62909 example]

then if you keep adding `1` to the value in SheetB!A1 the fill colours in SheetA!A1 should toggle red/pale blue.

The formulae I chose are of the type:

```
=iseven(indirect("SheetB"&"!A1"))
```