# Conditional formatting across documents

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I run several youtube channels and have an upload schedule for each.
I also have a master schedule that shows uploads across all channels. Each of these are different sheets within separate documents and they can't be combined
I've been manually changing cell colours (Red=planned, yellow=edited, green=live) and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to link cells so when I tick a checkbox on the upload schedule it will change the cell colour on the master schedule.
So if the "EDIT" checkbox is [TRUE] in document A then the cell colour will change from red to yellow in document B

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of cells that should be conditionally formatted the best way to proceed is to create a Google Apps Script on edit installable trigger.

Start by reading

1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
2. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
3. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

If you have only few cells or you don't want to read the above or find it too complex / time consuming you might want to try first to use formula for conditional-formatting. You  will have to use `IMPORTRANGE` to import the data from the spreadsheet with the checkboxes and if you add the `IMPORTRANGE` in not the sheet with the conditional formatting rules your conditional formatting formula should use `INDIRECT`.

Please bear in mind that `IMPORTRANGE` and `INDIRECT` will be recalculated frequently and this might affect your spreadsheets performance.

Resources

- [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)
- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Related

- [How can I set conditional formatting on a particular cell that depends on another cell's value?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16745/88163)
- [Conditional formatting across sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/62909/88163)